# Объясните, правильно ли я поставила знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

*Аня-не Аня, без пирсинга*.

Правильно ли я написала? Тире ведь и после запятой?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, неверно, никаких знаков препинания нет: Аня не Аня без пирсинга. Тире перед "не" не ставится.

Comment: Тире нет, потому что перед НЕ, интонационное нежелательно, потому что обратный порядок слов. Прямой: Аня без пирсинга - это не Аня

Answer (score 0):

Аня ― не Аня без пирсинга.

Ставится **интонационное тире**, обозначает паузу при  при логическом выделении подлежащего.

Comment: Не соглашусь.Интонационное тире было бы возможно, если б было: Аня без пирсинга - не Аня. В данном же варианте интонационное тире повлечёт за собой ещё один знак, чтоб отделить "без пирсинга", ведь смысл "Аня -не Аня, если она без пирсинга", иначе смысл запутывается. Но обычно такие конструкции пишутся без тире: я не я буду, ты не ты, у неё платье не платье(т.е очень дорогое, ценой в машину), машина не машина (элитная, ценой в дом)

Comment: Тогда надо остановиться на варианте "Аня без пирсинга  - не Аня". Совсем без знаков препинания предложение воспринимается с трудом.

Comment: Ну, это не нам решать, на чём остановиться. Нас спрашивают, как расставить знаки препинания в данном предложении. –

Comment: Значит, надо сказать автору, что предложение данной структуры  желательно изменить, так как  его  письменная запись  в исходном варианте затрудняет понимание высказывания.

Answer (score 0):

Совершенно не верно.

***Аня - не Аня без пирсинга. ***

Для запятой тут нет причин совершенно, а интонационное тире (вопреки Людмиле) тут нужно потому, что иначе совершенно не воспринимается. Но именно тире (с пробелами до и после), не дефис, как у вас.